# Webcam not detected

Tags: webcam

I have HP Pavillion dv6 running Ubuntu 16. The integrated webam is not working. I am unsure about the issue. When I run "cheese" in terminal, I get the following message:

```
** Message: cheese-application.vala:211: Error during camera setup: No device found
(cheese:3898): cheese-CRITICAL **: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed
(cheese:3898): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
(cheese:3898): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
(cheese:3898): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
(cheese:3898): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given
 ** (cheese:3898): CRITICAL **: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

Can somebody help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: only for keep this event in mind: Did you checked if your webcam is properly connected?. Time ago, I had a similar issue with a HP, and the problem was that, the webcam cables were disconnected for some reason. So, I connected it again, and Voila!

Comment: It is an integrated webcam. And it was working fine till morning.

Comment: Have you tried using the Live USB media and check if the webcam is functional there?.